# a problem on function and set

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

Let $F$ denote the set of all functions $f:\Bbb{R \to R}$ and let $Q\subset F$ be the subset of all continuos f  then prove that $\Bbb{|R|=}|C|<|F|$

Just give me a hint don't give a full solution

Comment: what is $C$? And as for your hint, you know that $|A|<|B|$ if  there exist function $g:A\rightarrow B$ such that $g$ is injective(one to one) funciton, but not surjective(onto) function.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean $Q$ and $C$ to be the same thing: the set of continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If so, here's your hint: Note that continuous functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are uniquely determined by their values on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: To prove the inequality, note that $|F|=|\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{R}|}=2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ and, by Cantor's theorem, $|\mathbb{R}|<2^{|\mathbb{R}|}$.